# ValueError: Could not interpret input

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have this data frame:

```
df = {'DATE':  [43390, 43599, 43605, 43329, 43440],
      'STORE': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
      'LYLTY_CARD_NBR': [1000, 1307, 1343, 2373, 2426],
      'TXN_ID': [1, 348, 383, 974, 1038],
      'PROD_QTY': [2, 3, 2, 5, 3],
      'TOT_SALES': [6.0, 6.3, 2.9, 15.0, 13.8]}

transac = pd.DataFrame(df)

    DATE    STORE   LYLTY_CARD_NBR  TXN_ID  PROD_QTY    TOT_SALES
0   43390   1         1000             1           2    6.0
1   43599   1         1307             348         3    6.3
2   43605   1         1343             383         2    2.9
3   43329   2         2373             974         5    15.0
4   43440   2         2426             1038        3    13.8
```

When I try to plot a boxplot from seaborn of the TOT_SALES column I get this error. The type of the column is float64. I tried the same with matplotlib and it worked but not with seaborn:

```
sns.boxplot(y='TOT_SALES', df=transac)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-29f35d075db2> in <module>
----> 1 sns.boxplot(y='TOT_SALES', df=transac)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth, whis, ax, **kwargs)
   2239     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2240                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 2241                           width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
   2242 
   2243     if ax is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
    441                  width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth):
    442 
--> 443         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    444         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    445 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    150                 if isinstance(var, str):
    151                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 152                     raise ValueError(err)
    153 
    154             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'TOT_SALES'
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: @pavel I found what was wrong. I type df instead of data in the plot code. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was caused by a typo, as per the OP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this issue because it's caused by a typo...`sns.boxplot(y='TOT_SALES', df=transac)` where `df=` should be `data=`.

Answer (score 24):

The source of your error is that you passed *transac* as *df*
parameter, which is not used by *seaborn*. Pass it as *data* instead:

```
sns.boxplot(y='TOT_SALES', data=transac);
```