# ValueError: Could not interpret value `ln(v)` for parameter `y`

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I appreciate there are a lot of discussions online about the value error: could not interpret input values with seaborn plots, as mentioned in ['Could not interpret input' error with Seaborn when plotting groupbys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908315/could-not-interpret-input-error-with-seaborn-when-plotting-groupbys), [ValueError: Could not interpret input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094143/valueerror-could-not-interpret-input), [ValueError: Could not interpret value for parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531969/valueerror-could-not-interpret-value-for-parameter)

But I realised my error was most likely caused by the version of seaborn. I tried two conda environments for the same code. One succeeded (seaborn version 0.13.0), whereas the other (seaborn version 0.11.2) output the ValueError: Could not interpret value `ln(v)` for parameter `y` and a warning message: /Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:36: FutureWarning: Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.

I was just wondering if anyone has experienced this before and whether the error message is indeed caused by the old version of seaborn? Maybe this does not have too much practical purposes but I am also curious about how to adjust the code so the old version seaborn would output a successful result.

My code is as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import os

# Read data

data = pd.read_excel("CG_features210224.xlsx",index_col=0)

# a 4x4 grid of subplots
num_rows = 4
num_cols = 4

# Set the size of the entire grid
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

# Iterate over each column in the dataset
for i, X in enumerate(data.columns, 1):
    # Create a subplot in the 4x4 grid
    plt.subplot(num_rows, num_cols, i)

    # Create a scatter plot for the current column
    sns.scatterplot(data, x=X, y="ln(v)", hue='temp', palette='coolwarm')

    # Set subplot title
    plt.title(f"{X}")

# Adjust layout to prevent overlap
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the entire grid of subplots
plt.show()
```

The detailed error messages are as below:

```
/Users/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:36: FutureWarning: Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.
  warnings.warn(

[0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------[0m
[0;31mValueError[0m                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input [0;32mIn [8][0m, in [0;36m<cell line: 3>[0;34m()[0m
[1;32m      3[0m [38;5;28;01mfor[39;00m X [38;5;129;01min[39;00m [i [38;5;28;01mfor[39;00m i [38;5;129;01min[39;00m data[38;5;241m.[39mcolumns]:
[1;32m      4[0m 
[1;32m      5[0m     [38;5;66;03m# Set the size of the plot[39;00m
[1;32m      6[0m     plt[38;5;241m.[39mfigure(figsize[38;5;241m=[39m([38;5;241m6[39m, [38;5;241m4[39m))
[0;32m----> 8[0m     [43msns[49m[38;5;241;43m.[39;49m[43mscatterplot[49m[43m([49m[43mdata[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mx[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mX[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43my[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[38;5;124;43m"[39;49m[38;5;124;43mln(v)[39;49m[38;5;124;43m"[39;49m[43m,[49m[43mhue[49m[43m [49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43m [49m[38;5;124;43m'[39;49m[38;5;124;43mtemp[39;49m[38;5;124;43m'[39;49m[43m,[49m[43mpalette[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[38;5;124;43m'[39;49m[38;5;124;43mcoolwarm[39;49m[38;5;124;43m'[39;49m[43m)[49m
[1;32m     10[0m     [38;5;66;03m# # Annotate each point with its label[39;00m
[1;32m     11[0m     [38;5;66;03m# for i, row in data.iterrows():[39;00m
[1;32m     12[0m     [38;5;66;03m#     plt.text(row[X], row['ln(v)'], row['Number'], fontsize=7, ha='left', va='bottom')[39;00m
[1;32m     13[0m     [38;5;66;03m#[39;00m
[1;32m     14[0m 
[1;32m     15[0m     [38;5;66;03m# Show the plot[39;00m
[1;32m     16[0m     plt[38;5;241m.[39mshow()

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:46[0m, in [0;36m_deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f[0;34m(*args, **kwargs)[0m
[1;32m     36[0m     warnings[38;5;241m.[39mwarn(
[1;32m     37[0m         [38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mPass the following variable[39m[38;5;132;01m{}[39;00m[38;5;124m as [39m[38;5;132;01m{}[39;00m[38;5;124mkeyword arg[39m[38;5;132;01m{}[39;00m[38;5;124m: [39m[38;5;132;01m{}[39;00m[38;5;124m. [39m[38;5;124m"[39m
[1;32m     38[0m         [38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mFrom version 0.12, the only valid positional argument [39m[38;5;124m"[39m
[0;32m   (...)[0m
[1;32m     43[0m         [38;5;167;01mFutureWarning[39;00m
[1;32m     44[0m     )
[1;32m     45[0m kwargs[38;5;241m.[39mupdate({k: arg [38;5;28;01mfor[39;00m k, arg [38;5;129;01min[39;00m [38;5;28mzip[39m(sig[38;5;241m.[39mparameters, args)})
[0;32m---> 46[0m [38;5;28;01mreturn[39;00m [43mf[49m[43m([49m[38;5;241;43m*[39;49m[38;5;241;43m*[39;49m[43mkwargs[49m[43m)[49m

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py:808[0m, in [0;36mscatterplot[0;34m(x, y, hue, style, size, data, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, style_order, x_bins, y_bins, units, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend, ax, **kwargs)[0m
[1;32m    793[0m [38;5;129m@_deprecate_positional_args[39m
[1;32m    794[0m [38;5;28;01mdef[39;00m [38;5;21mscatterplot[39m(
[1;32m    795[0m     [38;5;241m*[39m,
[0;32m   (...)[0m
[1;32m    804[0m     legend[38;5;241m=[39m[38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mauto[39m[38;5;124m"[39m, ax[38;5;241m=[39m[38;5;28;01mNone[39;00m, [38;5;241m*[39m[38;5;241m*[39mkwargs
[1;32m    805[0m ):
[1;32m    807[0m     variables [38;5;241m=[39m _ScatterPlotter[38;5;241m.[39mget_semantics([38;5;28mlocals[39m())
[0;32m--> 808[0m     p [38;5;241m=[39m [43m_ScatterPlotter[49m[43m([49m
[1;32m    809[0m [43m        [49m[43mdata[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mdata[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mvariables[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mvariables[49m[43m,[49m
[1;32m    810[0m [43m        [49m[43mx_bins[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mx_bins[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43my_bins[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43my_bins[49m[43m,[49m
[1;32m    811[0m [43m        [49m[43mestimator[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mestimator[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mci[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mci[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mn_boot[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mn_boot[49m[43m,[49m
[1;32m    812[0m [43m        [49m[43malpha[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43malpha[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mx_jitter[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mx_jitter[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43my_jitter[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43my_jitter[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mlegend[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mlegend[49m[43m,[49m
[1;32m    813[0m [43m    [49m[43m)[49m
[1;32m    815[0m     p[38;5;241m.[39mmap_hue(palette[38;5;241m=[39mpalette, order[38;5;241m=[39mhue_order, norm[38;5;241m=[39mhue_norm)
[1;32m    816[0m     p[38;5;241m.[39mmap_size(sizes[38;5;241m=[39msizes, order[38;5;241m=[39msize_order, norm[38;5;241m=[39msize_norm)

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py:587[0m, in [0;36m_ScatterPlotter.__init__[0;34m(self, data, variables, x_bins, y_bins, estimator, ci, n_boot, alpha, x_jitter, y_jitter, legend)[0m
[1;32m    571[0m [38;5;28;01mdef[39;00m [38;5;21m__init__[39m(
[1;32m    572[0m     [38;5;28mself[39m, [38;5;241m*[39m,
[1;32m    573[0m     data[38;5;241m=[39m[38;5;28;01mNone[39;00m, variables[38;5;241m=[39m{},
[0;32m   (...)[0m
[1;32m    581[0m     [38;5;66;03m# the kind of plot to draw, but for the time being we need to set[39;00m
[1;32m    582[0m     [38;5;66;03m# this information so the SizeMapping can use it[39;00m
[1;32m    583[0m     [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39m_default_size_range [38;5;241m=[39m (
[1;32m    584[0m         np[38;5;241m.[39mr_[[38;5;241m.5[39m, [38;5;241m2[39m] [38;5;241m*[39m np[38;5;241m.[39msquare(mpl[38;5;241m.[39mrcParams[[38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mlines.markersize[39m[38;5;124m"[39m])
[1;32m    585[0m     )
[0;32m--> 587[0m     [38;5;28;43msuper[39;49m[43m([49m[43m)[49m[38;5;241;43m.[39;49m[38;5;21;43m__init__[39;49m[43m([49m[43mdata[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mdata[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mvariables[49m[38;5;241;43m=[39;49m[43mvariables[49m[43m)[49m
[1;32m    589[0m     [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39malpha [38;5;241m=[39m alpha
[1;32m    590[0m     [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39mlegend [38;5;241m=[39m legend

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py:605[0m, in [0;36mVectorPlotter.__init__[0;34m(self, data, variables)[0m
[1;32m    603[0m [38;5;28;01mdef[39;00m [38;5;21m__init__[39m([38;5;28mself[39m, data[38;5;241m=[39m[38;5;28;01mNone[39;00m, variables[38;5;241m=[39m{}):
[0;32m--> 605[0m     [38;5;28;43mself[39;49m[38;5;241;43m.[39;49m[43massign_variables[49m[43m([49m[43mdata[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[43mvariables[49m[43m)[49m
[1;32m    607[0m     [38;5;28;01mfor[39;00m var, [38;5;28mcls[39m [38;5;129;01min[39;00m [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39m_semantic_mappings[38;5;241m.[39mitems():
[1;32m    608[0m 
[1;32m    609[0m         [38;5;66;03m# Create the mapping function[39;00m
[1;32m    610[0m         map_func [38;5;241m=[39m partial([38;5;28mcls[39m[38;5;241m.[39mmap, plotter[38;5;241m=[39m[38;5;28mself[39m)

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py:668[0m, in [0;36mVectorPlotter.assign_variables[0;34m(self, data, variables)[0m
[1;32m    666[0m [38;5;28;01melse[39;00m:
[1;32m    667[0m     [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39minput_format [38;5;241m=[39m [38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mlong[39m[38;5;124m"[39m
[0;32m--> 668[0m     plot_data, variables [38;5;241m=[39m [38;5;28;43mself[39;49m[38;5;241;43m.[39;49m[43m_assign_variables_longform[49m[43m([49m
[1;32m    669[0m [43m        [49m[43mdata[49m[43m,[49m[43m [49m[38;5;241;43m*[39;49m[38;5;241;43m*[39;49m[43mvariables[49m[43m,[49m
[1;32m    670[0m [43m    [49m[43m)[49m
[1;32m    672[0m [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39mplot_data [38;5;241m=[39m plot_data
[1;32m    673[0m [38;5;28mself[39m[38;5;241m.[39mvariables [38;5;241m=[39m variables

File [0;32m~/opt/anaconda3/envs/mdanalysis/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seaborn/_core.py:903[0m, in [0;36mVectorPlotter._assign_variables_longform[0;34m(self, data, **kwargs)[0m
[1;32m    898[0m [38;5;28;01melif[39;00m [38;5;28misinstance[39m(val, ([38;5;28mstr[39m, [38;5;28mbytes[39m)):
[1;32m    899[0m 
[1;32m    900[0m     [38;5;66;03m# This looks like a column name but we don't know what it means![39;00m
[1;32m    902[0m     err [38;5;241m=[39m [38;5;124mf[39m[38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mCould not interpret value `[39m[38;5;132;01m{[39;00mval[38;5;132;01m}[39;00m[38;5;124m` for parameter `[39m[38;5;132;01m{[39;00mkey[38;5;132;01m}[39;00m[38;5;124m`[39m[38;5;124m"[39m
[0;32m--> 903[0m     [38;5;28;01mraise[39;00m [38;5;167;01mValueError[39;00m(err)
[1;32m    905[0m [38;5;28;01melse[39;00m:
[1;32m    906[0m 
[1;32m    907[0m     [38;5;66;03m# Otherwise, assume the value is itself data[39;00m
[1;32m    908[0m 
[1;32m    909[0m     [38;5;66;03m# Raise when data object is present and a vector can't matched[39;00m
[1;32m    910[0m     [38;5;28;01mif[39;00m [38;5;28misinstance[39m(data, pd[38;5;241m.[39mDataFrame) [38;5;129;01mand[39;00m [38;5;129;01mnot[39;00m [38;5;28misinstance[39m(val, pd[38;5;241m.[39mSeries):

[0;31mValueError[0m: Could not interpret value `ln(v)` for parameter `y`
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: Your error probably means that there isn't a column named `"ln(v)"`.  Note that Pandas is very strict, e.g. there could be spaces in the real column name. Did you try `print(data.columns)` to verify? You can also look at `print(data.info())` to check that all the columns that are supposed to be numeric indeed are numeric.

Comment: The warning `Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x` means that seaborn now want all parameters to be explicitly named. So `sns.scatterplot(xs, ys)` should be `sns.scatterplot(x=xs, y=ys)`. That way, seaborn avoids confusion about what each parameter is intended to be. (This warning shouldn't pop up in the code as shown)

Comment: Yeah I have tried `print(data.columns)` and made sure the columns were all float or int. (the ln(v) one is a float column). And as I mentioned in the question I used exactly the same dataset and codes in two different environments with different seaborn versions, and one of them had no errors. I guess this might suggest it was not the problem of column names?
Also in my codes I indeed used sns.scatterplot(data, x=X, y="ln(v)") so this also made me wonder what did not work with seaborn version 0.11.2

Comment: I just checked with the very old `0.11.2` version.  It indeed gives that error. The problem with that version is it explicitly needs the `data=` keyword, as in `sns.scatterplot(data=data, x=X, y="ln(v)", ...)`. You can find the old documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/archive/0.11/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html). It's highly recommended to install the latest version, which constantly gets improvements and extensions (and the online documentation always expects to latest).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for checking it for me. Also it makes sense to use the latest version in this regard.